# How to redirect after success in recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to redirect the person to a location after captcha attempt is successful . I used this code , but this is not working.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "success")
  {
     function Redirect()
      {
         window.location.href = "example.com";
         }

           setTimeout(Redirect,1000);
            }
             else alert("You can't proceed!");
              </script>

  <div data-type="image" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey"></div>
```

I think it's not working because I don't understand https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify the api. Can you give an example of the code? I want to redirect after example.com after recaptcha success , else send him "You can't proceed"

Comment: You would need to verify the token server side. What language are you using there?

Comment: If you could provide a better context of your app, we could give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: In my website I want to a captcha box. It it success I want it to redirect in another page

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when the recaptcha returns 'success' you are creating a function called **Redirect** but you are not calling it, so you have to call the function after create it:

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "success") {
        function Redirect() {
            window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/";
        }

        Redirect()

        setTimeout(Redirect, 1000);
    } else alert("You can't proceed!");
</script>

<div data-type="image" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey"></div>
```

Or you can delete the function and redirect directly
 Make sure you are adding the full url:

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "success") {
        window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/";

        setTimeout(Redirect, 1000);
    } else alert("You can't proceed!");
</script>

<div data-type="image" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey"></div>
```

Comment: Your idea is correct, but what is the point of `setTimeout(Redirect,1000)`? It will cause an error since `Redirect()` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. Can you at least give me an example with only window.location.href . I don't need any time out redirection